# How do I get MySQLDataAdapter to set the table name and columns using TableMapping?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to gain an understanding of how TableMapping works. The code below should retrieve a single row from **[testing].[testtable]**:

| column_a | column_b |
| --- | --- |
| entry 1 | value 1 |
| entry 2 | value 2 |

I would like the retrieved *DataSet* to contain a table named **MyData** with the "*entry 1*" value in a column named **MyDataA** and the "*value 1*" value in a column named **MyDataB**.

However, the code below only names the table as desired. i.e.

**ds.Tables["MyData"].Rows[0]["MyDataA"]** throws an error while

**ds.Tables["MyData"].Rows[0]["column_a"]** returns "*entry 1*".

This is the opposite of what I want. I have tried reversing the parameters passed in the *dtm.ColumnMappings.Add()* statements, but to no avail.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or do I have a gross misunderstanding of what TableMapping is supposed to do?

```
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=testing;Uid=dev;Pwd=notmyrealpassword;AllowUserVariables=True;");
connection.Open();
    
var sql = "SELECT column_a, column_b FROM testtable WHERE column_a=@p1;";
    
var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "entry 1");
    
var dtm = da.TableMappings.Add("testtable", "MyData");
dtm.ColumnMappings.Add("column_a", "MyDataA");
dtm.ColumnMappings.Add("column_b", "MyDataB");
    
var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "MyData");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `da.Fill(ds, "testtable");`
At the moment you're filling the data adaptor with your table and calling it "MyData". But you want to call it "testtable" so it can be linked with the "MyData" table mapping and *then* you can access your column mappings.

Though you could also alias your names in the query if that's easier, save fiddling with mappings

```
SELECT column_a as MyDataA, column_b as MyDataB 
   FROM testtable 
   WHERE column_a=@p1;
```

Comment: That worked ! ! !  Thankyouthankyouthankyouthankyou !
My frustration level was getting very high.

Happy holidays, everyone

Comment: No problem, You too!

Comment: By "That worked" I meant filling "testtable". I can see how the aliasing would work too, but, for my actual use case, it would just complicate things.